# Modal verb after 'In all probability'

Tags: modal-verbs, modality

Which modal verb comes after 'in all probability' ?
For example 'In all probability it will/may/can rain tonight. 
Which modal is appropriate?

Comment: Look at the examples in: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+all+probability. The majority use **will** after the expression, although it's often abbreviated with an apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*will* is the most appropriate here. By using 'in all probability', the implication is that the event is likely, but not guaranteed to happen. Therefore, *can* or *may* would be redundant- that'd be like saying it *probably may happen* - two words are doing the same thing.

> In all probability, it will rain tonight.